# Building farms with IBM Websphere, IBM Http Server, Load Balancer (or Dispacher)

Tags: architecture, websphere, web-architecture, ibmhttpserver

Do you know a web page or pdf or any books to learn how to architecture these products to create a farm?

Also any generic web application farm architecture best-practices source is appreciated ...

I would like to learn about highly available and scalable web architecture especially using IBM products...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the IBM Redbooks site, maybe [WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment V6: High Availability Solutions](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246688.html?Open).

> IBM Redbooks publications are
>   developed and published by the IBM
>   International Technical Support
>   Organization (ITSO). The ITSO develops
>   and delivers skills, technical
>   know-how, and materials to IBM
>   technical professionals, Business
>   Partners, clients, and the marketplace
>   in general.

Answer (score 1):

I came across an interesting article[1] this morning that talks about how to make large clusters in WAS to handle extremely high workloads.

-Rick

[1] http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0906_banerjee/0906_banerjee.html